# What data should I track during member registration and logins?

Tags: data, usage-data

I am working on a membership registration process and hung up on what data I should store during the registration and login processes.

Does it benefit me to track how long my members are onsite? How often they visit? As for the registration process, the registration date would be of value.

I want to understand and determine site satisfaction and usage. If you were gathering usage data, what would be the most valuable items (and why)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/) tracking code for a start. That will give you all the user behaviour you need , but you should also set up event tracking to track which buttons are clicked. You can also link these to goals where relevant so that you can measure conversation rates, but you also need this if you’re using [Google AdWords/Ads](https://ads.google.com/home/).

There are other options for tracking but most are paid for and are costly, Google Analytics is free.

Also use [HotJar](https://www.hotjar.com/) or something similar for heat maps and recording sessions. This will give you huge visibility over what’s happening on your site.

These tools don't sell your data or pass it onto your competitors so it is kept private, only people with the login details to the tools I have suggested have access to the data.

The only alternative is you make your own version of these tools yourself!

Not using Google Analytics because they have access to your data is like not using an email provider because they'll have access to your emails. I think your position on keeping your data completely private will limit your options when it comes to SEO. As in SEO you will need to use tools like [web crawlers](https://raptor-dmt.com/seo-tools/web-crawler/), Heat map tools, [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about), and a range of other off the shelf solutions to problems.

Comment: Wouldn't using a third party product give away all of your valuable data to that third party? I'd prefer to keep my data private. Can you revise your answer?

Comment: Its not like you're giving it to your competitors, you're buying a tool or using an off the shelf solution. Your data would be private, Some data is even kept private from you in Google Analytics, such that you can't identify specific people. I really wouldn't worry about Google or HotJar having access to your data, they are enabling you to collect and analyse it.

Comment: Has this helped to both answer your question and reduce the perceived risk to your privacy?